# Export Mathematica 8 plot to TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to generate a plot in Mathematica 8 and then somehow export the data so that I can plot it using TikZ? I do not like how Mathematica's plots are rendered and would like to use proper LaTeX fonts.

This is not a simple case of just plotting a simple function, i.e. I might as well just type the plot commands in TikZ; The generated expressions I want to plot are fairly horrible and long.

EDIT: Currently in Mathematica I do something like:

```
Plot[

RecurrenceTable[
 ...
]
 {w, 0, 10}
]
```

Where I am calculating the recurrence table of a coupled set of non-linear recurrence relations up to some `n`. Each term is a function of `w`. I hope this is helpful. I doubt that I want to do the calculation using TeX.

Comment: Do you have trouble importing your data from Mathematica or replotting them via TikZ?

Comment: What type of plot are you going to make? An 1d line plot? scatter? 2d surface plots? In case of 2d: is orthogonal projection sufficient? In any of these cases, pgfplots might be of help - where it would probably be the best approach to import table data into pgfplots (nonlinear systems of equations are unsupported ;-) ).

Comment: Export the plot data as a text (csv for example) file, say col x and col y, and then import into latex?

Comment: I have asked a similar question in mathematica.stackexchange.com http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2377/mathematica2tikz-an-equivalent-function

Answer (score 4):

Well, ideally, if you use TikZ + [PGFPlots](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pgfplots.html), then you can basically do many things. We might elaborate if you have a particular example in mind.

Answer (score 4):

There is always the round-about way with exporting the entire graphic as an EPS. Then, using [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) or [`psfragx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfragx), you can substitute tags or labels in the rendered EPS with LaTeX text; almost like a search-and-replace.